# Regular expression to find string within tags

Tags: python, regex, xml, expression

Does anyone have some guidance on how to make a regular expression to find all the string within `<time>` and `</time>`? There are 3 cases of this in the code below. I have to use regular expression to return the 3 strings between time and /time in a list.

```
<tabular>
  <time from="2015-09-23T23:00:00" to="2015-09-24T00:00:00" period="3">
    <!-- Valid from 2015-09-23T23:00:00 to 2015-09-24T00:00:00 -->
    <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04" />
    <precipitation value="0" />
    <!-- Valid at 2015-09-23T23:00:00 -->
    <windDirection deg="118.5" code="ESE" name="East-southeast" />
    <windSpeed mps="1.2" name="Light air" />
    <temperature unit="celsius" value="12" />
    <pressure unit="hPa" value="1010.4" />
  </time>
  <time from="2015-09-24T00:00:00" to="2015-09-24T06:00:00" period="0">
    <!-- Valid from 2015-09-24T00:00:00 to 2015-09-24T06:00:00 -->
    <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04" />
    <precipitation value="0" />
    <!-- Valid at 2015-09-24T00:00:00 -->
    <windDirection deg="94.7" code="E" name="East" />
    <windSpeed mps="1.9" name="Light breeze" />
    <temperature unit="celsius" value="12" />
    <pressure unit="hPa" value="1010.4" />
  </time>
  <time from="2015-09-24T06:00:00" to="2015-09-24T12:00:00" period="1">
    <!-- Valid from 2015-09-24T06:00:00 to 2015-09-24T12:00:00 -->
    <symbol number="4" numberEx="4" name="Cloudy" var="04" />
    <precipitation value="0" minvalue="0" maxvalue="0.3" />
    <!-- Valid at 2015-09-24T06:00:00 -->
    <windDirection deg="122.9" code="ESE" name="East-southeast" />
    <windSpeed mps="2.6" name="Light breeze" />
    <temperature unit="celsius" value="12" />
    <pressure unit="hPa" value="1009.3" />
  </time>
</tabular>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "three strings"?

Comment: Sorry, i ment the three matches.

Comment: You want the XML contents of all the time elements, as strings? In any case, I'd strongly recommend using a proper xml library like ``lxml`` rather than regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, correct. I've tried used re.findall(), but I get no matches when I try.
I want to solve this with regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

It is an xml file, so instead of using regex, why don't you use `XPATH`. You can use python library called `lxml` for this purpose as it supports `XPATH` language. I don't know your exact use case, but sample code should be somethink like :-

```
from lxml import etree

xml_doc = etree.fromstring(xml_string) # assuming xml_string is xml_content

xpath_expression = '/tabular/time/text()' # change it according to your use case

data = xml_doc.xpath(xpath_expression)
```

[XPATH Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xpath/)

Answer (score 1):

This will grab the contents of each of the time element, as is:

```
re.findall("<time[^>]*>(.*?)<\/time>",xmldata, re.DOTALL)
```

I'd still recommend an XML library over regular expressions though.

If you want the `time` elements themselves in there too, then use this:

```
re.findall("<time[^>]*>.*?<\/time>",xmldata, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree

xmlString = '''<tabular>
...'''

tree = etree.fromstring(xmlString)

res = []

for timeNd in tree.xpath('//tabular/time'): 
    res.append(''.join([etree.tostring(node) for node in timeNd]))

print(res)
```

The XPath query `//tabular/time` selects all `time` nodes, then for each nodes, child nodes strings are concatenated and the resulting string is appended to the list `res`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`re.findall(r'<time[^>]*>.*?<\/time>', 'XMLSTRING', re.DOTALL)`

Comment: This almost worked, but it just returned the entire string in a list.
I need the string seperated, so in this case, It should have returned a list with 3 elements.

Comment: edited to include the '?' to make it non-greedy. Sorry.

Comment: See @clasG's answer as well, which has the brackets to capture the matches

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<time[^>]*>(.*?)<\/time>
```

It returns three match groups. Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/aT6kU4/1) (Note the `global` and `singel line` flags)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done because XML is not a regular language (that's a technical term in computer science). Any attempt will either catch some strings you don't want to catch (for example an XML comment designed to confuse your regex matcher) or will fail to catch some strings that you should match (e.g. elements containing comments in places where you didn't expect them). To process XML, always use an XML parser.